# Fastest way to draw ellipse in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, gdi, hardware-acceleration

I need to draw a lot of small ellipses (c. 60 000) on a 2D bitmap. In my experience, GDI+ or NGraphics proved to be very slow for this kind of tasks. I would like to be able to achieve at least 10 fps, which doesn't seem to be too ambitious, but I don't know how.

As video games do that kind of stuff very efficiently, I am tempted to think this is a problem of hardware acceleration. But I saw in another question that GDI+ is supposed to be 2D-accelerated, so maybe there is something else I didn't get.

My question is not about flickering or double buffering. It is really a question of pure speed : what is the fastest way to draw simple shapes (pixels, lines, ellipses) on a bitmap.

Comment: Are you talking about 60k * 10 frames  = 600k ellipses per second?? Try to go for WPF, which will make use of DirectX..

Comment: Yes I am talking about 600k ellipse per second. That's why I think I need to use a GPU for this task, so DirectX is a good idea. Thanks

Comment: wpf won't be able to do that as the overhead is too big. It is directx accelerated but the cpu still does most of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try OpenTK. It uses OpenGL and is very fast. You can get the result of the drawing operations and convert it back to a Bitmap if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try OpenGL too.

Answer (score 1):

In GDI the *fastest way* would be to get a [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) object (e.g. within the OnPaint() method) and call e.g. [`DrawEllipse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt06kxfd.aspx) on it.

But you had to check on yourself if maybe not all of them are visible and skip these. Also you can try to tweak performance by setting the [`CompositingQuality`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.compositingquality.aspx), [`InterpolationMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode.aspx), [`PixelOffsetMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pixeloffsetmode.aspx) and [`SmoothingMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode.aspx) of the graphics object.

But maybe using a different technique like WPF, OpenGL or DirectX would make more sense. Maybe even switching to [Unity](https://unity3d.com) could be an options. But thats a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SkiaSharp, it's faster than GDI +, but I don't know if it can handle 600K lines/s.

## SkiaSharp

C# / .Net wrapper of Skia

Documentacion of SkiaSharp  [SkiaSharp managed by "Xamarin/Microsoft"](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/graphics-games/skiasharp/introduction)

Documentacion of Skia library[skia.org](https://skia.org/).

## Usage SkiaSharp

1. Add NuGet package `SkiaSharp`
2. Add `using SkiaSharp`;
3. Draw Ellipse/oval `canvas.DrawOval ( cx,  cy,  rx,  ry, paint)`

Code for drawing ellipses:

```
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create (width: 640, height: 480, SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul)) {
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        Color = Color.Red.ToSKColor(),
        StrokeWidth = 10
    };
    canvas.DrawOval ( cx,  cy,  rx,  ry, paint)
}
```

Parameters:
**cx** The center x-coordinate.

**cy** The center y-coordinate.

**rx** The vertical radius for the oval.

**ry** The horizontal radius for the oval.

**paint** The paint to use when drawing the oval.